# Is there a logic error with my implementation of odeint?

Tags: python-3.x, ode

I am getting the wrong solution and am unsure if odeint is the correct tool for solving this system of ODEs.

I am trying to model a simple first order chemical reaction by solving a system of ODEs. From a logic standpoint my functions are correct and I can solve this problem in MATLAB with little issue. I would like to also be able to do this work in python as well. I think odeint is the tool for the job but I could be wrong. My solution should not converge at independent variable = 10 every time but it always does regardless of inputs.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import (plot,grid,xlabel,ylabel,show,legend)
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import odeint

wght= np.linspace(0,20)
# reaction is A -> B
def PBR(fun,W):

    X,y = fun

    P_0=20;#%bar
    v_0=5; #%m^3/min
    y_A0=1; #unitless
    k=.005; #m^3/kg/min
    alpha=0.1; #1/kg
    epi=.13; #unitless
    R=8.314; #J/mol/K

    F_A0= .5 ;#mol/min

    ra = -k *y*(1-X)/(1+epi*X)


    dX = (-ra)/F_A0
    dy = -alpha*(1+epi*X)/(2*y)

    return [dX,dy]

X0 = 0.0
y0 = 1.0


sol = odeint(PBR, [X0, y0],wght)


plot(wght, sol[:, 0], 'b', label='X')
plot(wght, sol[:, 1], 'g', label='y')
legend(loc='best')
xlabel('W')
grid()
show()
print(sol)
```

Output graph
[image: Output graph]

Answer (score 0):

Your graphic is not reproducible, in python 3.7, scipy 1.4.1, I get a divergence to practically infinity at around 12.5, and after cleaning the work space, both graphs moving to zero after time 10.

The problem is your division by `2*y` in the second equation. In effect that means that `y` is the square root of some other function, and that type of function behaves badly numerically at small values as the tangent becomes vertical, changing to zero shortly after.

However, one can desingularize the division in a simple way

```
    dy = -alpha*(1+epi*X)*y/(1e-10+2*y*y)
```

or in a more complicated way that leaves the solution far away from zero really unchanged

```
    dy = -alpha*(1+epi*X)*y/(y*y+max(1e-12,y*y))
```

resulting in the graph

[image]

If that is still not the expected behavior, then something else is different in your ODE system relative to the Matlab version.

That the singular point is at about `w=10` depends almost completely on `alpha=0.1`. As `epi` is small and `X` is initially small, the second equation is close to

```
d(y^2)/dW = -alpha  ==>  y^2 = 1 - alpha*W
```

and this hits zero at about `W=10` where the solution would have to end as the square of `y` can not take negative values.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that the alpha value I was using wasn't physically correct anyway and when correcting, my solution becomes reasonable. I did not realize the effect it was having.